# How to control wxCheckListBox items?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I create a wxCheckListBox and add some items in it.Need to control them if any of items be checked I want to do some functions.Actually this is a cheat dll application.

```
wxArrayString pSkills;//this is array for my list
```

```
wxCheckListBox* SkillList = new wxCheckListBox(Panel1, wxID_ANY, wxPoint(3, 3), wxSize(150, 200), pSkills);//my list
```

I can control and load items whatever I need.

```
bool MainFrame::IsChecked(unsigned int uiIndex) const
{
    if (IsChecked(uiIndex) == true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else { return false; }
}
```

I use this for control.

```
SkillList->Bind(wxEVT_CheckListBox, &MainFrame::IsChecked, this);
```

And I use this didn't work:)

Comment: please define what doesn't work and how it doesn't work? Can you show the code for `MainFrame::IsChecked()`?

Comment: @Igor I define this 
`void check(wxCommandEvent& event);`

Comment: `void MainFrame::check(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    if (event.IsChecked() == true)
    {
        
        wxMessageBox(wxT("Hello World!"));
    }
    else{ wxMessageBox(wxT("Doesn't Work!")); }
}` and this is for checkbox but I need to find and trying every ways I found :S

Comment: the `Bind()` call should use `MainFrame::check`

Comment: doesn't let me to use.Gives error.And that check function is for CheckBox.Not for CheckListBox.My mood is down :S really need to find this :(

Comment: Please check the proper event name: `wxEVT_CheckListBox` vs `wxEVT_CHECKLISTBOX`

Comment: @Igor No have any example

Comment: check the documentation and/or the official sample.

Answer (score 0):

`wxCommandEvent::IsChecked()` only works for the events from checkboxes and menu items. To get the current state of an item `N` in the listbox you need to use `SkillList->IsChecked(N)`.

Comment: `    
bool check = SkillList->IsChecked(0);
    if (check)
    {
        wxMessageBox(wxT("Hello World!"));
    }` I use like that didn't work!

Comment: This does work if the first item is checked.

Comment: Has to pops up message box if its work when I select first item in the list but not works.Can you please help me about this if you have discord or any others @VZ.

Comment: my Discord Metin#1114

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code snippet below.

```
class MainFrame
{
private:
    wxCheckListBox *SkillList;
public:
    MainFrame(/*set of parameters*/);
}

MainFrame::MainFrame(/*set of parameters*/)
{
    SkillList = new wxCheckListBox(Panel1, wxID_ANY, wxPoint(3, 3), wxSize(150, 200), pSkills);//my list
    SkillList->Bind( wxEVT_CHECKLISTBOX, &MainFRame::check, this );
}

void MainFrame::check(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    if( SkillList->IsChecked( 0 ) )
        wxMessageBox( "Item 0 is checked" );
}
```

Also, I strongly advise you to start using sizers.

Look at the code, compare with what you have, understand you issues and only then use it in your program.

Comment: I'm so appreciate.You don't know how badly I worked on this problem.Really thank you so much. Acctually I'm new with wxWidgets.I dont know what is sizer @Igor

Comment: and I understand what you mean.Thanks for your advise.